# Why is ASP.NET Core 2 not automatically loading dependent assemblys running on .NET 4.7.1?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-standard

When I create an ASP.NET Core 2 application targeting. net Framework 4.7.1 and reference other projects containing controllers I noticed that ASP.NET Core 2 automatically loads dependent assemblies running on .NET Standard.
I just have to reference them from my main web application and I can immediately hit the controllers from the referenced project.
When the assembly is a assembly on the full .NET Framework (4.7.1 in my case) I see that this assembly is not automatically loaded as `ApplicationPart` and the Controllers are not available.
When I manually add the full .NET Framework Assembly during startup with

```
services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(FullController).Assembly);
```

everything works as expected and I can use the controllers from this assembly as well.

Is there a specific reason for this behavior? 
And is it safe to add my full .NET Framework Assembly this way?

Comment: Does your ASP.NET Core 2 app target .NET Core or .NET Framework? That's a very important piece of information you should state clearly.

Comment: @LexLi The main web application is targeting .NET Framework 4.7.1. I updated the description.